# Android: How to use YoutubePlayer for local video files?

Tags: android, video, youtube

I am building an app to upload videos to Youtube.

After user recorded a video I want to preview the video to the user. I want to make the preview to be as close as possible to the real thing on youtube. Therefore I want to use youtube player.

How to play local videos with [YoutubePlayer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer)?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it would work with what you want but you have the youtube api for android.

The YouTube Android Player API enables you to incorporate video playback functionality into your Android applications

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: It wasn't what you were looking for ?